# porque me cambia la fecha mi variable js

Tags: javascript, html

estoy tratando de recibir mi variable dentro de una variable tipo date
el problema es que me cambia mi fecha
por ejemplo
selecciono 2022 y me regresa 2024

aqui un ejemplo del boton que cambia la fecha
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui la pura variable de fecha dentro de mi new date
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui dejo mi codigo

```
// llegada de la IDA elegida
                var v_fFechaLlegadaIDA = document.getElementById("FechaLlegadaSalida").value;
                var v_hHoraLlegadaIDA = document.getElementById("HoraLlegadaSalida").value;
                //extrae año, dia, mes de IDA
                let añoextraidoida = v_fFechaLlegadaIDA.substring(6, 10);
                let mesextraidoida = v_fFechaLlegadaIDA.substring(3, 5);
                let diaextraidoida = v_fFechaLlegadaIDA.substring(0, 2);
                //extrae minutos,horas de IDA
                let horaextraidoida = v_hHoraLlegadaIDA.substring(0, 2);
                let minutoextraidoida = v_hHoraLlegadaIDA.substring(3, 5);

           var llegadaIDA = new Date(añoextraidoida, diaextraidoida, mesextraidoida, horaextraidoida, minutoextraidoida, 0, 0);
                console.log("valida la llegada separada", llegadaIDA);
```

asi tengo la forma en que recibo mi variable
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var v_fFechaLlegadaIDA = document.getElementById("FechaLlegadaSalida").value;
```

aqui agrego mi console.log

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agrege el split

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Robert Mendoza como son los inputs que tienes ene l html ? donde coges el valor tipo texto y con que formato tienes la fecha yyyy/mm/dd ?

Comment: utiliza moment.js para que tu codigo no se extienda tanto y asi no tener este tipo de problemas

Comment: la recibo como string en una variable value, pero mi otra fecha que agrege si me aparece bien sin problema, ya agrege esa parte en la pregunta como lo esta recibiendo

Comment: agrege mi console.log

Answer (score 4):

A menos que estés usando alguna librería, el formato de los [campos tipo fecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) es `aaaa-mm-dd`, pero estás intentando obtener los datos como si fuera `dd-mm-aaaa`. Aparte, estás invirtiendo mes y día al crear la [nueva fecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) y, de acuerdo a la documentación, es necesario restar 1 al mes:

> Valores enteros con las representaciones de las partes de una fecha. Como valor entero, **el mes se representa de 0 a 11, con 0=enero and 11=diciembre**.

```js
let v_fFechaLlegadaIDA = document.getElementById("FechaLlegadaSalida").value;
let v_hHoraLlegadaIDA = document.getElementById("HoraLlegadaSalida").value;
// El formato de los campos tipo fecha es: aaaa-mm-dd
console.log('Verificar formato del campo: ' + v_fFechaLlegadaIDA);

//extrae año, dia, mes de IDA
let añoextraidoida = v_fFechaLlegadaIDA.substring(0, 4);
// Restar 1 a mes, porque debe ser de 0-11
let mesextraidoida = parseInt(v_fFechaLlegadaIDA.substring(5, 7)) - 1;
let diaextraidoida = v_fFechaLlegadaIDA.substring(8, 10);
//extrae minutos,horas de IDA
let horaextraidoida = v_hHoraLlegadaIDA.substring(0, 2);
let minutoextraidoida = v_hHoraLlegadaIDA.substring(3, 5);

// El orden de los parámetros es: Año, mes, día, hora, minuto
var llegadaIDA = new Date(añoextraidoida, mesextraidoida, diaextraidoida, horaextraidoida, minutoextraidoida);

console.log(añoextraidoida, mesextraidoida, diaextraidoida, horaextraidoida, minutoextraidoida);

console.log("valida la llegada separada", llegadaIDA);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="FechaLlegadaSalida" value="2022-05-17">
<input type="time" id="HoraLlegadaSalida" value="15:30">
```

Una opción más simple para obtener los datos es separarlos con [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) y, aprovechando la [desestructuración](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), asignas fácilmente las variables:

```js
let v_fFechaLlegadaIDA = document.getElementById("FechaLlegadaSalida").value;
let v_hHoraLlegadaIDA = document.getElementById("HoraLlegadaSalida").value;
// El formato de los campos tipo fecha es: aaaa-mm-dd
console.log('Verificar formato del campo: ' + v_fFechaLlegadaIDA);

// Cada elemento está separado por guion
// Crea variables con nombres más cortos, sin caracteres especiales
let [fIdaA, fIdaM, fIdaD] = v_fFechaLlegadaIDA.split('-');
// Restar 1 a mes, porque debe ser de 0-11
fIdaM = parseInt(fIdaM) - 1;

console.log(fIdaA, fIdaM, fIdaD);

//extrae minutos,horas de IDA
let horaextraidoida = v_hHoraLlegadaIDA.substring(0, 2);
let minutoextraidoida = v_hHoraLlegadaIDA.substring(3, 5);

// El orden de los parámetros es: Año, mes, día, hora, minuto
var llegadaIDA = new Date(fIdaA, fIdaM, fIdaD, horaextraidoida, minutoextraidoida);

console.log("valida la llegada separada", llegadaIDA);
```

```html
<input type="date" id="FechaLlegadaSalida" value="2022-05-17">
<input type="time" id="HoraLlegadaSalida" value="15:30">
```

En caso de estar usando una librería que te devuelva otro formato de fecha, solo acomoda las variables para que cada una tenga el dato que le corresponde y asegúrate de enviar los parámetros en el orden correcto al crear la fecha.

Comment: excelente muchas gracias

Comment: solo que marz trae como fecha en vez de febrero

Comment: @RobertMendoza, cierto, edité la respuesta. Se debe restar 1 a mes para que sea de 0 a 11.